# Python List to List of Dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, logic

I have the follow list

```
lines = 
    [['client', 'name', 'phone', 'address', 'email'],

     ['client2', 'name2', 'phone2', 'address2', 'email2'],

     ['client3', 'name3', 'phone3', 'address3', 'email3']]
```

I would like to know if it's possible turn a list into a list of dic.

like:

```
lines = 
    [{Client: client, Name:name, Phone:phone, Address:address, Email:email},

     {Client: client2, Name:name2, Phone:phone2, Address:address2, Email:email2},

     {Client: client3, Name:name3, Phone:phone3, Address:address3, Email:email3}]
```

Comment: Your desired output is not a valid dictionary, since there are multiple values for a single key. For example, `Client` could be `client` or `client2`.

Comment: How about a list of dictionaries?

Comment: I got it, so maybe I can say a list of dictionaries ?

Comment: Linebreaks do not break lists!

Comment: Neither the input is a valid list (missing commas...)

Comment: Where is client1? Are the first five elements in the list like columns, or are they going to be client1's information?

Comment: [collections.namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) could be useful here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, here's what I think you want. First you need a list of what all the keys should be called:

```
>>> keys = ["Client", "Name", "Phone", "Address", "Email"]
```

Then, it's very easy to go from a list with as many items as the keys to a dict:

```
>>> info_list = ["Client #1", "Joe", "800-213-4445", "123 Fake St.", "fake@fake.com"]
>>> dict(zip(keys, info_list))
{'Email': 'fake@fake.com', 'Phone': '800-213-4445', 'Client': 'Client #1', 'Name': 'Joe', 'Address': '123 Fake St.'}
```

Now if you have 36 items instead, all you need is a list of 36 keys.

Comment: the problem is, I have too many values to make like the first example, if I try, I get the follow error: "ValueError: too many values to unpack"

Comment: @Luiz.brsp: how did you try to call it? It means you're trying to give it 6 or 7 elements instead of 5

Comment: Actually It's a list of list and each list has 36 'items'. (thank you for your attention!)

Comment: @Luiz.brsp: Ok, in the question you have a list of 3 lists, and each inner list has 5 items. what do you actually have?

Comment: In my real situation I have a list of thousand list, and each inner list has 36 items.

Comment: @Luiz.brsp: Ok. so you want to turn that into a list of a thousand dictionaries, each dictionary with 36 items? What do you want the keys of the dictionary to be called?

Answer (score 1):

Providing "lines" is a list of list, you could turn it into a list of dictionnaries, like this :

```
clientList = []
for line in lines:
    clientList.append({'Client':line[0],
                       'Name':line[1], 
                       'Phone':line[2], 
                       'Address':line[3], 
                       'Email':line[4]})
```

Answer (score 0):

A start:

```
lines = [client, name, phone, address, email,
         client2, name2, phone2, address2, email2,
         client3, name3, phone3, address3, email3]

linesD = {entry: entry for entry in lines}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't make a single dictionary with them all, but you could make a list of dictionaries -- and here's how I would do it:

```
lines = [
    client, name, phone, address, email,
    client2, name2, phone2, address2, email2,
    client3, name3, phone3, address3, email3,
]

keys = ('Client', 'Name', 'Phone', 'Address', 'Email')

clients = [dict(zip(keys, lines[i:i+5])) for i in xrange(0, len(lines), 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

cause your data is not nice-formatted, i change it a little...

```
import pandas as pd
...
lines = [
    [client, name, phone, address, email],
    [client2, name2, phone2, address2, email2],
    [client3, name3, phone3, address3, email3]]
fields=["Client", "Name", "Phone", "Address", "Email"]
s = pd.DataFrame(lines, columns=fields)
# choose one u want:
print(list(s.T.to_dict().values())
print(s.to_dict(outtype='list'))
print(s.T.to_dict())
```